# Is there a way to find out the exact source tree for specific Raspberry Pi kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, raspbian

I'm trying to compile a kernel module on my raspberry and I keep getting 'disagrees about version of symbol module_layout' when trying to load the compiled module.

I would like to avoid compiling the whole kernel so what I'm doing is using the img produced by the Raspberry pi foundation here (http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest), then trying to install the kernel source from https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux and the Module.symvers from https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/extra/Module.symvers

I think the problem is that I'm not hitting the combination of kernel sources and Module.symvers that matches what's on the laster RPi Images. I wish the github repo was labelled but it's not.

Is there a way to know what branch/commit was used to create the latest raspbian for Rpi release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that after reading a few more forums, I came across an answer. Here it is:

1. Find out the firmware commit used to create the image on your Rpi run:

```
    zgrep "* firmware as of" /usr/share/doc/raspberrypi-bootloader/changelog.Debian.gz | head -1 | awk '{ print $5 }'
```

2. List item

Find out the linux source commit used to create the firmware by seeing the contents of **https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/*firmware_commit*/extra/git_hash**

 3. Install the Linux sources on your raspberry pi:

```
    cd /usr/src/
    sudo wget https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/archive/source_commit.tar.gz
    sudo gunzip source_commit.tar.gz
    sudo tar -xvf source_commit.tar
    sudo mv linux-source_commit linux
    sudo ln -s linux linux-headers-3.18.5+ (user your kernel version instead of 3.18.5+)
    sudo ln -s linux /lib/modules/3.18.5+/build
```

This is a bit unrelated but still useful if you'd like to compile a kernel module without having to compile the whole kernel:

```
    cd /lib/modules/3.18.5+/build
    sudo make mrproper
    sudo sh -c 'zcat /proc/config.gz  > .config'
    sudo wget https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/raw//extra/Module.symvers
    sudo make modules_prepare
```

After this you should be able to compile your module.

Comment: For the Module.symvers, that is throwing a 404. I needed to use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/firmware/73da926dbe5bb31e8b18ba782c7577a7127ad740/extra/Module.symvers